# PowerShell - Query E-Mail from AD (pause function not working)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

**What this script does:**

You enter part of a user's Display Name and the script prints the user's E-Mail address from an AD query.

```
$displayname=Read-Host -Prompt 'Type part of Display Name'
$displayname=$displayname+"*"
get-aduser -Filter {displayname -like $displayname} -Properties mail,displayname | Select displayname,mail
&pause
```

**What my problem is:**

I am struggling with the "pause" function.

At the end of the script I want to pause the script so I can actually see the results.
But for some reason the script always executes the pause function before printing the actual AD query results.

I tried various different methods like:

```
cmd /c Pause | Out-Null
```

or

```
write-host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

or

```
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

or

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
```

All ending up with the same behavior.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting a problem that rises from the fact Poweshell doesn't wait for `Get-ADUser` to return. For a work-around, can you pipe the results to `Out-GridView`?

Comment: Have you tried adding a sleep before the pause? That might give the AD query long enough to return? I can't replicate the issue. When I run your code it is returning as expected for me, then pausing.

Comment: Piping the result to `Out-Host` seems to work as well: `Select displayname,mail | out-host `

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. It is really funny that PowerShell does not wait for Get-ADUser to finish. I've used the out-host method now, as you never know how long the query takes, and therefore the out-host is the most elegant way in my opinion. Pryz, if you post your comment as answer, I'd be happy to mark it as solution.